# How to set value variable from checkbox checked laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Họ và tên</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nhập tên" name="username" value="{{old('username')}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nhập địa chỉ email" name="email" value="{{old('email')}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Mật khẩu</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Nhập mật khẩu" name="pass1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nhập lại mật khẩu</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Nhập lại mật khẩu" name="pass2">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cbadmin" value="1" {{old('cbadmin') ? "checked" : ''}} > Admin
                  </label>
                </div>
```

I want set value variable $lv =1 while checkbox "cbadmin" checked. But not know how to retrieve it. I want set default lv=0, lv=1 if checkbox checked.

```
public function getAdd(AddUserRequest $request)
    {
        User::create([
            'name' => $request->username,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->pass1),
            'level' => ????
        ]);
        return redirect('admin/manage-user/add')->with('success','Bạn đã thêm thành công!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `input()` with a default value for the case of `cbadmin` being unchecked:

```
User::create([
    'name' => $request->username,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->pass1),
    'level' => (int)$request->input('cbadmin', 0)
 );
```

Comment: Done. Thank you. I even forget set fillable column "level" in Model User.

Answer (score 2):

You could check whether `cbadmin` exists in the `$request`. If it exists, it was checked and then you could set $lv to 1.

```
$lv=isset($request['cbadmin'])?1:0;
```

Comment: Done. Thank you. I even forget set fillable column "level" in Model User.